# Passing any variable value from Java to JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, android

I'm using a webview in my android application, and the web address that the webview loads contains some JavaScript. Now, I just want to know if it is possible to pass in some variable values from my Java Code to my JavaScript.

Here's my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById (R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new transferPlaceId(), "Android");
    webView.loadUrl("http://webaddress.com/directory/page.html");
```

}

Javascript Interface works well, no need to worry about it.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you call that javascript or the web address from your java code ?? are you consuming that webservice or something else ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You could pass them as URL parameters in the querystring, then use JavaScript to look at the querystring and get the values back out.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Can you please give me some links or tutorials? Thanks.

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html refer this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can

```
String name = "foo";
webView.loadUrl("javascript:functionName('"+name+"')");
```